# Javascript Find User

Tags: javascript

I have the below javascript to get the UserID from a online form. This script will go through IE DOM Explorer to find the valued. But when I run the script, it is totally ignoring my "If" statement. It is just providing a value for "NewAuthUserID", without considering the "if".

```
(function () {
  var NewAuthUserID = "";
  var UserId = $('tr.background-highlight:contains("REQUESTER PROFILE") + tr').children('td:contains("User ID:")+td').text();
  if ('tr.background-highlight:contains("NEW AUTHORIZED INDIVIDUAL PROFILE:"') {
    var NewAuthUserID = $('td:contains("User ID:")+td:eq(2)').text();
  };
  alert(UserId);
  alert(NewAuthUserID)
})();
```

Comment: Basically you have `if(non-empty_string)`. In JavaScript it's `truthy`.

Comment: It would be much, much easier to think about if it wasn't on a single line.

Comment: Your `if` statement is non-sensical. What did you mean to compare something to?

Comment: @DaveNewton: probably simply forgot to wrap with jquery

Comment: @SergioTulentsev even so, that particular jquery selector still won't eval to true/false.  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp

Comment: @ShaunSweet: yes, but if you slap `.length` to the end, it becomes a "booleanable" expression. Not sure if that's what they meant, though

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd suggest to check out how the if statement works: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

You need the if statement conditional to return true or false.  Right now you're TRYING to use jquery to select things but even that has a syntax issues.  Not only that but once the syntax is fixed it STILL won't do what you're attempting to do because you're putting something that will always evaluate to true as the conditional.  That jquery selector just returns a function, not a boolean like it looks like you're intending to do.  Try this:

```
(function(){
    var NewAuthUserID = "";
    var UserId=$('tr.background-highlight:contains("REQUESTER PROFILE") + tr').children('td:contains("User ID:")+td').text();
    if($('tr.background-highlight').text() == "NEW AUTHORIZED INDIVIDUAL PROFILE:")){
      var NewAuthUserID=$('td:contains("User ID:")+td:eq(2)').text();
    }
    alert(UserId);
    alert(NewAuthUserID)
  })();
```

Notice how I'm snagging the text that you're trying to test against with jquery and expressing it with a conditional instead?  In this manner, it will return the boolean: true/false which is what you need to get the if statement to trigger.

Also if you check your syntax, you were missing the $() wrapper around your if statement, but you have a string that looked like it was trying to snag text via jquery.

Comment: Your proposed "improvement" changes the check entirely. It's only valid when there's one matching tag, and fails if there are several.

Comment: Shaun, I just input the script and it is not running at all. As Sergio indicated, there are multiple tag with that name and I want the If function to action only when it finds the specified tag.

Comment: Oh I see.  I misunderstood the intent of your code.  Can you just loop thru the array of selected elements and check if the text matches?

Comment: Hello Shaun, I am able to run this code but it is still ignoring the IF condition even when the word "New Authorized Individual Profile" is there.

Comment: Can you post that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest formatting your code a bit, this always helps to debug.

The problem is you are trying to use a jQuery selector in your if statement, but you didn't include the $ to evaluate jQuery. It's just evaluating a string, wich results in TRUE (basically doing this: `if(true))`, so the code block is executed. 
Try this instead:

```
javascript: (function() {
  var NewAuthUserID = "";
  var UserId = $('tr.background-highlight:contains("REQUESTER PROFILE") + tr').children('td:contains("User ID:")+td').text();
  if ($('tr.background-highlight:contains("NEW AUTHORIZED INDIVIDUAL PROFILE:"').length > 0) {
    var NewAuthUserID = $('td:contains("User ID:")+td:eq(2)').text();
};
  alert(UserId);
  alert(NewAuthUserID)
})();
```

EDIT: I added the length > 0 check on the returned object. It's possible to accomplish this with OP's code, he was just missing those two pieces. `:contains` is not the same as `.text() ==`.

Comment: What? That's the same non-sensical `if` statement.

Comment: Your if statement will always return true.  You're just putting a string in as the conditional.

Comment: Updated the answer with lengh > 0. I forgot about ```prevObject``` & junk in jquery and assumed it would return false/emtpy when the selector didn't match.

Comment: Ricas01 I am unable to run this script. I tried my best to see if anything missing, but unable to find any.

Answer (score 0):

#### Off topic response:

The way you manage/select your nodes may require a lot of maintanance in the future and is prone to errors.

For example: `tr.background-highlight:contains("REQUESTER PROFILE") + tr` 
In words: Get me the table-row *after* a table-row with hilighted background, that contains `"REQUESTER PROFILE"`.

What if you'll have to add a row in between them? what if you'll need to select the row, wether it is hilighted or not? what if further rows will be hilighted in the future, so that this selector ain't uniqu anymore? what if the label changes? maybe even the language? ...

In each of these cases you'll have to revisit *(potentially all)* your jquery selectors, just because some minor layout changed. 
*That's not very reliable.* 
Will you remember that when you'll get asked to do these changes? Maybe someone else will have to do these changes, will he/she know what to look for?

Tell me, do you remember the details/implications/quirks of the work you've done a week ago? not to speak about your work from a few months ago.

#### Better:

Use "unique" identifier to, well, identify your nodes by their role; and I'm not talking about IDs. Unique within their specific context.

The easiest way would be to use css-classes. Annotating the rows/cells so you can select the very same field as `$('.ref-requester-provile .ref-user-id')`

This is way more reliable and future-proof than your bulky `$('tr.background-highlight:contains("REQUESTER PROFILE") + tr').children('td:contains("User ID:")+td')` where your JS needs to know every little detail of your template/markup, and needs to be adapted with every little change.

*Why did I prepend these classes with `ref-`? to distinct them from classes that are meant for styling*

If you don't need to style these nodes and need these identifyer solely to reference them in your JS, I'd rather use a `data`-attribute. Why? Let's sum it up with:

- performance: when you need to add/remove these marker; avoid unnecessary render-cycles
- A cleaner seperation between style and code: classes are primarily for styling, but we don't style here.